# OrderBy on Eloquent whereHas relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a simple page which lists counties and there related items under headings. These items need to be `approved`, hence the whereHas method.

I currently have the following eloquent query;

```
$counties = County::whereHas('items', function ($query) {
    $query->where('approved', 1);
})->get();
```

The `items` returned are currently ordered by their primary field `id` (it would seem), however I want to list these items alphabetically by their `name` field.

I have tried the following query, but this does change anything. Any advice would be appreciated?

```
$counties = County::whereHas('items', function ($query) {
    $query->where('approved', 1)->orderBy('name');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you want to display the result , try this :

```
@foreach($counties as $county)
    @foreach($county->items->orderBy('name') as $item)
          {{ $item->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Or in your County Models :

```
public function approvedItems(){
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class)->where('approved', 1)->orderBy('name');
}
```

and then :

controller :

```
$counties = County::whereHas('approvedItems')->get();
```

view :

```
@foreach($counties as $county)
    @foreach($county->approvedItems as $item)
          {{ $item->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Try to work with your models and relationships for having the lightest controller you can, you will gain in lisibility

Answer (score 1):

```
$counties = County::whereHas('items', function ($query) {
    $query->where('approved', 1);
})->orderBy('name')->get();
```

I don't think you can order on the subquery, it should be before the ->get

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Unfortunately this order's the `county` results rather than the `items`. Is there another way to achieve this perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

To keep it eloquent, you can put it in the relation, in the Model class:

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class)->orderBy('id','desc');
}
```

https://laravel.io/forum/09-14-2015-ordering-a-collection-by-the-related-items

Might be late, but hopefully someone stumbles on this (it's the first in google search)

Comment: This also does not work since it sorts the relation itself, not the parent query. It is basically the same code that the question has.

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = Topic::with('latestPost')->get()->sortByDesc('latestPost.created_at');
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, please add additional information as to _why it works_.

Comment: 'sortBy' after the ->get() rather than 'orderBy' means that it's PHP doing the ordering, rather than SQL. This can lead to some performance/memory issues if you have thousands of results to sort.